# Unable to send files + form_data with POST AJAX Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Using the GET Method, I am able to successfully send Form Data + Files + Other Data to PHP using AJAX. I get the desired results -- $_GET & $_FILES

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.php?controlData="+controlData+"&form_data="+thisFormElements,true);
xmlhttp.send(files);
```

However, with the POST Method, I am not able to get $_FILES in PHP, I am not sure how I can send files + FormData with xmlhttp.send() to PHP, so I get $_GET & $_FILES both

I wish to achieve this with Javascript only and not Jquery if possible

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "data.php", true);  
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xmlhttp.send("controlData="+controlData+"&form_data="+thisFormElements+files);
```

PFB the entire Ajax Code

```
            function ajax(controlData,thisFormSubmitElement){
                var controlData = JSON.parse(controlData);
                controlData = JSON.stringify(controlData);
                var todiv = controlData['todiv'];
                var form_vals = [];
                var form_nams = [];
                var formkeyvalobj = {};
                var thisFormElements = thisFormSubmitElement.form.elements;
                var files = new FormData();

                // Creating Key value pair for form elements BEGINS
                for(var x = 0; x < thisFormElements.length; x++){
                    if(thisFormElements[x].type === "file"){
                        var fileToUpload = document.getElementById(thisFormElements[x].id);
                        files.append(thisFormElements[x].name, fileToUpload.files[0]); 
                        form_vals[form_vals_len] = ""; 
                        form_nams[form_vals_len] = thisFormElements[x].name;
                        formkeyvalobj[form_nams[form_vals_len]] = form_vals[form_vals_len];
                        }else{
                        form_vals[form_vals_len] = thisFormElements[x].value;
                        form_nams[form_vals_len] = thisFormElements[x].name;
                        formkeyvalobj[form_nams[form_vals_len]] = form_vals[form_vals_len];
                    }
                }
                thisFormElements = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(formkeyvalobj));
                // Creating Key value pair for form elements ENDS

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 || this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 401) {
                        document.getElementById(todiv).innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };

                // GET METHOD WORKS - In Php I Get $_GET & $_FILES

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.php?controlData="+controlData+"&form_data="+thisFormElements,true);
                    xmlhttp.send(files);   

                    // POST METHOD DOES NOT WORK - In Php I Get $_POST BUT I DO NOT GET --- $_FILES

                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "data.php", true);  
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                    xmlhttp.send("controlData="+controlData+"&form_data="+thisFormElements+files); 
                }
```

Comment: use `xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "key": "value", "key2": "value",...});`